# Windows 7 computer gets locked when it shouldn't

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 system that gets locked. It didn't used to until I changed some settings like enabling the screen saver and resume with password. AFAIK, I have reversed the settings. For example, it never sleeps.

The computer still gets locked automatically. What are the computer settings which cause the computer to lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "resume with password" is the problem.  As the screensaver comes on it automatically locks the machine for you when this setting is enabled.

Comment: When I said I reversed the settings, I meant I turned off the screen saver, after turning it on. However later I found out even though the screen saver was set to "none", the "resume with password" checkbox was checked and that caused the screen saver to still launch. I am not sure if this is a bug. Anyway, I will accept this answer just because it made me check the setting again.

Comment: "resume with password" could be better described as "require a password when retuning from a unnateded state".